# Closing questions - off topic reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see that the list of reasons to close an off topic question are just a few. 
[image: Close reasons]

How about adding a few more?
First one that comes in mind

> Question is about third party module support.

An other one could be (taken from SO)

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I think the First availabil is already a good match for lack of sufficient informations. But yeah, would make it easier to flag really bad posts with no informations.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely Pro

> Question is about third party module support.

Already have flagged a few posts for closing because of this.

Comment: +1 but there are a few 3rd party products we seem to not have a problem supporting as a community (think Magmi)

Comment: Ok, I think we should extend the message a bit with a hint they should contact the support contact of the module or open an issue on github, when its hostet there.

Comment: It's not practical to allow some 3rd party module questions and not others. Given how small this community is surely the odd one that sneaks through isn't an extra noise that we can't bare. Especially considering how the site is not over-ran by complete novice coders like you may find in stackoverflow. If someone is struggling with a 3rd party extension and another member happens to know the answer (given that the question wouldn't exist without magento in the first place) why not let it be

Answer (score 2):

The additional information should be asked in a comment as author can not be aware which info is required to answer the question.